# Change default colours in ggplot for labels by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a plot made with ggplot where the points are labelled with the text of the 'project' and the colour of the team. I would like to be able to change the colours assigned to each team as the default ones aren't very legible. I have tried most ways of doing this I've found online but none have had any effect.

I've included the whole code below - the bit of interest is under '#Labels coloured by team'.

```
    projects.df <- data.frame(Doability = Projects$Doability, Impact = Projects$Impact)
ggplot(projects.df, aes(Doability,Impact)) + 
  #Coloured Quadrants
  annotate("rect", xmin = Inf, xmax = 0.5, ymin = Inf, ymax = 0.5, fill= "darkseagreen1")  + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = 0.5 , fill= "azure1") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.5, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.5, ymax = -Inf, fill= "lightyellow") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.5, xmax = -Inf, ymin = Inf, ymax = 0.5, fill= "mistyrose") + 
  geom_point() + xlim(0,1)+ ylim(0,1) +
  #Labels coloured by team
  geom_label(aes(label=Projects$Project), colour=factor(Projects$Team), fontface = "bold") + 
  #Axis arrows
  geom_segment(aes(x=-Inf,y=-Inf,xend=-Inf,yend=Inf),size=1.5, colour="darkred", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5,"cm"))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=-Inf,y=-Inf,xend=Inf,yend=-Inf),size=1.5,colour="darkgreen", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5,"cm"))) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), clip="off")
```

Comment: Hi.. you can color by using scale_color_manual and it's not called at all in the code above. I also noticed that you called color outside aes: geom_label(aes(label=Projects$Project), colour=factor(Projects$Team), fontface = "bold"). This will give you weird results.

Comment: Can you do dput(head(Projects,6)) and paste the output as part of your post? Otherwise we never know what went wrong with the plotting

Comment: I had tried to use scale_color_manual but it wasn't working as my colour was in the wrong place - thanks, it's all solved now I've moved it inside aes.

Comment: you can add the answer for new learners

Answer (score 0):

Moving colour to inside aes call, as per comments, solved the problem and I could call "scale_color_manual" [sections #Labels coloured by team and #colours below].

`projects.df <- data.frame(Doability = Projects$Doability, Impact = Projects$Impact)
ggplot(projects.df, aes(Doability,Impact)) + 
  #Coloured Quadrants
  annotate("rect", xmin = Inf, xmax = 0.5, ymin = Inf, ymax = 0.5, fill= "darkseagreen1")  + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = 0.5 , fill= "azure1") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.5, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.5, ymax = -Inf, fill= "lightyellow") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.5, xmax = -Inf, ymin = Inf, ymax = 0.5, fill= "mistyrose") + 
  geom_point() + xlim(0,1)+ ylim(0,1) +
  #Labels coloured by team
  geom_label(aes(label=Projects$Project, colour=factor(Projects$Team), fontface = "bold")) + 
  #Axis arrows
  geom_segment(aes(x=-Inf,y=-Inf,xend=-Inf,yend=Inf),size=1.5, colour="darkred", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5,"cm"))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=-Inf,y=-Inf,xend=Inf,yend=-Inf),size=1.5,colour="darkgreen", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5,"cm"))) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), clip="off") + 
  #Colours
  scale_colour_manual(values = cbp1) + labs(colour = "Team")`